# How can I minify and concatenate a dir full of JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, webpack, browserify

I'm working on a **legacy** Ruby on Rails 4 codebase.

It contains hundreds of `.js` files...

```
$ find app/assets -name '*.js' | wc -l
  268
```

In production mode, it isn't so bad because the Rails Asset Pipeline minifies them and concatenates them into one file.

But in development, page refreshes take an **extremely** long time.

I don't think they need to load in a specific order, but I'm not 100% sure.

I want to compile (minify and concatenate) **only** a specific subdir (recursively) of JavaScript files **in development mode.**

Is there some tool I can point at a dir and output one minified `.js` file?

Ideally, this would be something that could **watch** a dir and recompile on changes.

I suspect that maybe Browserify or Webpack might be able to do that, but it isn't obvious to me from the docs how it would work in practice.

Comment: Are you calling files via @import or =*require ?

Comment: No. The previous developers included them via a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Do the files depend on a specific order? If so, how do you determine that?

Comment: If most of these files only need to be called on specific pages and not application wide I can post an answer how to utilize the asset pipeline for page specific loads.  It will help reduce the load time on changes but won't involve concatenating anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Go ahead and post your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen See update in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grunt to concat/minfy all your js(or a subset). However, if you update one, you need to recompile manually.

http://gruntjs.com/